# Refused PLAB visa last year, reapplying now

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, business-travel, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-employment

I visited my sister in UK last year for 6 months sep-mar 2014, for which I got family visitors visa during which I had cleared my PLAB 1 and had vacation with my sister and her family in UK. Immediately after my exit from UK, I applied for a business visitor visa for PLAB 2 exam, which was refused on the grounds of my intention to *defacto* residence in UK with multiple entries with 1 year my stay would be of more than 6 months, and I didn't show any employment details.

Now after 1 year I am reapplying visa for PLAB exam, I have an employment letter, payslips and a sponsorship letter from my sister with all her supporting documents. But my account has only 20000 rupees I.e £200, my dad has £5000 in his account and my sister(in UK) has 3000£ in her account. Would this be sufficient or should I make any changes now? Kindly guide me how to apply in a better way to avoid refusal this time. Should I show my salary getting deposited in my bank statement or payslips are enough?